# Elasticsearch query converting UTC to PST

Tags: elasticsearch

I am running a date_histogram Elasticsearch query based on a particular time stamp range.  I would like to convert the output from UTC to PST.  I am running it from now to the previous 7 days ("gte": "now-7d/d").  What do I need to add to convert the output from UTC to PST which is a difference of 8 hours?  I researched using the "time_zone" function but I thought that was converting a particular time to UTC ("time_zone": "+01:00").

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any easy way (if any) to change the contents of `key_as_string` field in aggregation result. But, you can very well convert `key` field which has epoch to PST date in your application.

I hope this is useful.